# excel add cell if percentage or dollar amount

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I have a total column and want to add to that total a cell that would house either a percentage or a dollar amount, what is the formula?  Is that possible.?

For example
a1 = freight
b1 would be either $5.00 or 5%
c1 would be total of a1, plus the dollar of percentage amount of b1

how do I get c1 to be the total of a1, plus either $5.00 or 5% that is in b1?  It would be either/or.  Thanks you

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are here to help with what you have so far. So, what have you attempted to get this to work? How does Excel know which to use, $5.00 or 5%?

Comment: Hi Charlie:  That is my dilemma, I don't know how to get Excel to know whether my amount is a dollar figure and should be added, or a percentage, that should be multiplied.  Do I need to have two separate cells - one for $ and the other for %?

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing how you determine whether is gets $5 or 5%.

Comment: Sorry Charlie - I am new to this and trying to self teach.  f the freight is less than $100 I use $5.  If it is over $100 I use 5%.  Regina

Comment: Thank you Charlie - I actually understand it too which is the best thing!   I am so appreciative.

Comment: Have you tried Joe's answer below? It should be what you need to be able to accomplish this. If his answer is acceptable, please mark it with a check mark under the voting buttons to the left.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Excel can distinguish between a decimal and a percentage internally.  Percentages are purely representational; a percent sign just means 'divide by 100' to get the decimal and is more for the benefit of human eyes than Excel's internal logic. So it really has no way to tell whether you're talking about 5 cents or 5%.

What you can do is get the format with `=CELL("format",B1)` and if the first character of the result is a P I think it's telling you that you have a percentage. P2 would mean a percentage with 2 decimal places, as in 3.14% or something.

So try `=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",B1),1)="P","Percentage","Not percentage")` to see whether your cell is a percent or not.

If it works to your satisfaction, you could do  `=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",B1),1)="P",A1+(A1*B1),A1+B1)`

Disclaimers: The solution is dependent on formatting, which could be confusing. It's probably better to do as you said and make separate columns for unlike data.  No idea how reliable this is, but if you're sure you entered everything correctly and correctly distinguished the percentages as percentages it should work. Also, I use LibreOffice, not Excel; in LibreOffice, it doesn't seem to update the results properly when I change the format.

Comment: A1? Dependent on "either $5.00 or 5% that is in b1", no? If B1 is $5, she wants to add $5 to A1 to get C1.  If B1 is 5%, she would want to multiple A1 by 0.05 and add that amount to A1 to get C1. To do that conditionally, you need to know whether or not the value in B1 is a percentage, and to know that you need to look at the formatting. I fixed a mistake though.

Comment: No problem. Upon reading the comments under the question more closely, I also see your point!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, give this a try in cell b1.

=IF(A1<100,A1+5,A1*1.05)

Since you are trying to self teach:

```
IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

Further explanation can be found here:

[IF function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/IF-function-a918d97a-251e-4af5-bd15-09b12b8742bb)